# Custom \big command

Tags: macros, equations, brackets, customize

I have a lot of equations with double parenthesis and I want the outside one to be bigger. I've been using:

```
\big(w(B)\big)
```

which gives me this result

[image]

But my obsession was killing me, I didn't like so much space between the parenthesis, therefore I created two commands

```
\newcommand{\bigparl}{\big(\hspace{-0.1em}}
\newcommand{\bigparr}{\hspace{-0.1em}\big)}
```

Which give me this:

[image]

But I was wondering if there was a way to create a more general command `\custombig` that would work like `\big` does. So that I can just say `\custombig(w(B)\custombig)` or `\custombig[w(B)\custombig]` and it would add the symbol ( or [ with the negative space -0.1em.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: never use `\big` as you see, the horizontal space is wrong. `\big` is just the internal helper for `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` which have math open and math close spacing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `\bigl` and `\bigr` to preserve the `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` classes of `(` and `)`.

that also makes it easy to have commands adding space correction. It's better to use `mu` space than `em` but `\!` (3mu =3/18 em) is a bit tight so I used 2mu here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\biglx[1]{\bigl#1\mspace{-2mu}}
\newcommand\bigrx[1]{\mspace{-2mu}\bigr#1}
\begin{document}

$\log\big(w(B)\big)$

$\log\bigl(w(B)\bigr)$

$\log\bigl(\!w(B)\!\bigr)$

$\log\bigl(\mspace{-2mu}w(B)\mspace{-2mu}\bigr)$

$\log\biglx(w(B)\bigrx)$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a different approach.  The `\Comp` macro embraces its argument in parens and vertically grows the outer parens .4pt higher and lower.  I t also can reduce the horizontal spacing around parens (here shown with a 1pt shrinkage).

Thus, nested groups will automatically grow the parens in a predictable way.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\ignoremathstyle
\newcommand\Comp[1]{\scaleleftright{(}
  {\kern-1pt\addstackgap[.4pt]{#1}\kern-1pt}
  {)}}
\begin{document} 
\[ 
\Comp{x\Comp{w\Comp{Q}}}
\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]